# Minecraft modding my effects are not working

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

My problem is that like you have seen in the title my effects are not working when I put them on my player
This is my code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
    public void onCopperBlockSneak(InputUpdateEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getMovementInput().sneaking)
        {
            PlayerEntity player = event.getPlayer();

            ItemStack mainHand = player.getHeldItemMainhand();

            BlockPos blockPos = player.getPosition().down();
            BlockState block = player.world.getBlockState(blockPos);

            if (block.getBlock() == ModBlocks.COPPER_BLOCK.get())
            {
                if (mainHand.getItem() == ModItems.COPPER_WIRE.get()) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.STRENGTH, 100));
                    player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.REGENERATION, 100));
                    player.addPotionEffect(new EffectInstance(Effects.FIRE_RESISTANCE, 100));

                    mainHand.shrink(1);

                    String msg = TextFormatting.RED + "YOU JUST ENTER IN GOD MODE !!!";
                    player.sendMessage(new StringTextComponent(msg), player.getUniqueID());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: Does the event works ? Have you well register it ?

Comment: Yes the event works well i have the effects that appears at the top of my screen but I don't have the "super strength" for example even if I have the thing on my screen

Comment: and you test it in server ?

Comment: no why you think it can help me?

Comment: because it's possible that you add effect, but they are only client side, not server side

Comment: how do i verify this?

Comment: if you are not on server, isn't not possible. But I think you can check on a creative world on local, with cheat enabled

Comment: i already checked it but my effects are not applied